# django rest framework generate file link from frontend(8000) domain not backend(8080)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF for backend and React for frontend.
In DRF I return link to my local saved file.
Django application takes 8080 port and react 8000.
And when I create *Request* from Frontend, DRF return path to file with localhost:8000/media/...
I need localhost:8080/media/...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DbEO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be because your backend responded with `/media/<file_name>` because of this your frontend will add `http://localhost:8000/` before the file response.

If you are working in the local environment then you have to change media response by joining your backend URL with file response.

for your solution:

1. Add BACKEND_URL in your DRF settings as `http://localhost:8080/`
2. in the model which stores media file add a `@property`

   ```py
   class TempModel(models.Model):
      file = models.FileField()

      @property
      def get_file_url(self):
          from urllib.parse import urljoin
          from django.conf import settings

          return urljoin(settings.BACKEND_URL, self.file.url
   ```
3. Add `get_file_url` in your serializer and use it as the source to the file. OR change your serializer as below so that the response will change in the `file` field automatically.

   ```py
       class TempModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
            file = serializers.URLField(sourc="get_file_url", read_only=True)
            # other part of the serializer
   ```

> NOTE: if you use the last option of serializer, make sure you can upload the file from the same API or for better reason change the API to add or update files only. but it is up to your system architecture.

Comment: It helps I will test it again interesting. Thank you for the fast response.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. If you appreciate the answer, don't forget to mark it as correct.